# How do I fix IE7 right float bug without changing order of content

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have list items, with a span, set to inline-block and floated right.  This is the result

[image: HTML layout]

Here's a link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bR3u/.
I've seen several suggestions to fix this by putting the span in front of the rest of the list item content, but I want a solution that doesn't jack up the markup.  Anyone know of one?

Comment: Did you set a width on the floated elements?  Show use your code or make a jsfiddle, it should clear things up.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - added jsfiddle to question

Comment: On an unrelated note, this markup seems like a prime example for using a definition list instead of an unordered list. In fact, switching from a unordered list to the more semantic (in this case) definition list might even remove the need for a bug fix.

Comment: @Moses - Good idea, except that ultimately this will go into a CMS for client use, and definition lists don't work so well for client input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix required can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/8bR3u/4/

The fix is to add position:relative to the ul and add position:absolute and top:5px and right:0px to the span and remove the float.

The solution is to use Relatively Absolute positioning. More info on it can be found here http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/